# How can one prevent HTTP-authentication Brute Force Attacks, on PHPmyadmin with CSF-LFD?

Tags: php, brute-force

I use PHPmyadmin (PMA) to manage my SQL based DB on an Apache environment secured with CSF-LFD (that as I know, also called "Fail2ban").

I don't want to protect PMA by limiting it to a certain IP or to remove and install it each time anew.

In contrast, I do secure PMA with basic HTTP-authentication and picked up a nice password for the root user but my question is where and what directives should one add to make sure CSF-LFD covers Brute Force Attacks for this one.

Comment: You could use Fail2Ban to firewall off hosts after a certain number if failed attempts. The best way would be to simply use something that can't be bruteforced like an HTTPS client certificate.

Comment: Sadly I don't have spare budget (and currently, possibly also the spare time) to implement SSL. Must I have it to block surfers that will try to log in more than say, 3 times?

Comment: @Benia Do you know LetsEncrypt? SSL/TLS does not necessarily cost something, nowadays.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add these lines to your Apache Config to log failed authentications

/etc/apache2/conf.d/phpmyadmin.conf:

```
LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\" %{userID}n %{userStatus}n" pma_combined
CustomLog /var/log/apache2/phpmyadmin_access.log pma_combined
```

Then create the fail2ban filter:

/etc/fail2ban/filter.d/phpmyadmin.conf

```
[Definition]
denied = mysql-denied|allow-denied|root-denied|empty-denied
failregex = ^<HOST> -.*(?:%(denied)s)$
ignoreregex =
```

Now add the jail to /etc/fail2ban/jail.local

```
[phpmyadmin]
enabled = true
port = http,https
filter = phpmyadmin
logpath = /var/log/apache2/phpmyadmin_access.log
```

Restart apache and fail2ban:

```
service  apache2 reload
service fail2ban reload
```

Comment: I don't have /etc/fail2ban ...

Comment: @Benia Then you don't have it installed ... `apt-get install fail2ban`

Comment: Oh, my brother told me that "Fail2ban" is the old name of "CSF-LFD"... From what you write above, it seems he was mistaken.

Comment: Or else when you say "CSF-LFD" you mean to another software called Fail2ban, and not to this CSF-LFD program: https://download.configserver.com/csf/install.txt

Comment: Fail2ban and CSF are two independent programs. CSF never is fail2ban, and fail2ban never is CSF.

Comment: So if I understand correct from the answer, it actually doesn't even involve CSF-LFD, in any way ?

Comment: @Benia Yes, exactly.

Comment: Ok, but the way you've edited your question now makes my answer seem completely unrelated.

Comment: I honestly didn't think it would matter... I rolled back the edit.

Comment: Please one last thing, you say "Now add the jail to /etc/fail2ban/jail.local". Do you mean to create this file? Because the only "jail" files I have there are jail.d && jail.conf, BUT NOT jail.local...

Comment: http://www.fail2ban.org/wiki/index.php/MANUAL_0_8 here under Configuration: jail.local is commonly used to override settings. The default jail.conf can be reset by package managers and therefore should not store changes. So yeah, create it.

Answer (score 0):

CSF supports dynamic blocking of HTTP Basic Authentication failures natively, using the `*HTACCESS*` configuration items in `csf.conf`, usually found as `/etc/csf/csf.conf`. This also includes  'client denied by server configuration' log items that produce 403 Forbidden errors.

```
# [*]Enable login failure detection of Apache .htpasswd connections
# Due to the often high logging rate in the Apache error log, you might want to
# enable this option only if you know you are suffering from attacks against
# password protected directories
LF_HTACCESS = "5"
LF_HTACCESS_PERM = "1"
```

Search for `HTACCESS` in `csf.conf` for the related options. Note that some of the actual config options have other names, such as `LF_APACHE_403`, but most of them mention `HTACCESS_LOG` in the comments.

These all depend on the `HTACCESS_LOG` file/path location configuration item, to know what log file to monitor - so make sure that is correct.